# How to build a navigation menu for long-form texts like this one

Tags: plugins, menus, navigation

A menu like this one here (on the right–hand side) – http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/docs/ – makes it much easier to navigate through long-form texts.

Do you know of a way of implementing something like this in WordPress so that you can navigate to each heading in a longer text?

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is http://scrollnav.com.

We use this for Aesop Story Engine in our Chapter and Timeline components.